# Asp.Net GridView Adding Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have been pulling my hair for the good majority of today. On a project I have imported a datasource from a stored procedure in SQL Server. I am binding that DataSource to a GridView and here comes my question is there a way to basically make the same row of information being imported through the Stored Procedure so when I hit Edit I can change some of the values on the second row and then show the edited results on the third row? I have been trying to figure out how I would even go about doing this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a generalize stored procedure which should basically take a parameter for Edit/Insert/Delete command. Also you need to pass the parameters to the stored procedure for the columns to be updated.
Than basically you need to modify GridView Event handlers for rowEditing, insert to call the stored procedure and update the records.
which will basically call the stored procedure with the parameters to update the database. 
I have found a very good example of this being done with step to step guide.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-CRUD-Select-Insert-Edit-Update-Delete-using-Single-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet.aspx

Try following this article. This one is doing exactly what you need to achieve.

Thanks